# how to look up two (or more) app Ids with appstore API?

Tags: ios, api, app-store, itunes

I know I can search for specific application in app store via iTunes (app store) API or even look up an app Id and get json using this :

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284882215

and also I know I can search using app bundle or search all application by one developer,

but is there any way to look up for two applications and get their jsons in one file?

for example I want to have Facebook and Twitter iTunes's jsons in one file, how to achive that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

it was simpler than it seems! just use comma (,) as seprator!

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1st_APP_ID,2nd_APP_ID,3rd_APP_ID
```